# Sub type not recognized serialization

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, xml-deserialization

[image]

Translated:

> An error has occurred while trying to display the type
>   AnmialShelter.Animal

I have a Animal class with multiply sub classes like a 'horse' and a 'mouse'.

I write the animal to an XML like this:

```
private void writeToFile() 
    {
        DataContractSerializer dcs = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Animal));

        using (FileStream f = new FileStream(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory) + @"\file.xml",
               FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            foreach (Animal a in animalList)
            {
                    dcs.WriteObject(f, a);
            }
        }
    }
```

When i try to read the xml and add the objects to a animal list the error as seen in the image.

```
private List<Animal> readFromFile()
{

   var myDeserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Animal));

   using (var myFileStream = new FileStream(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory) + @"\file.xml", FileMode.Open))
   {
       animalList = (List<Animal>)myDeserializer.Deserialize(myFileStream);
   }

    return animalList;
}
```

Comment: Can you translate the error into English, please?

Comment: Sorry see edit: An error has occured while trying to display the type AnmialShelter.Animal.

Comment: Why are you using different serializers (`XmlSerializer` and `DataContractSerializer`)?

Comment: Just a stab in the dark - it might be because `Animal` is (potentially) an abstract class?